# Show Current Value in Android App Settings

Tags: java, android, settings

I am trying to make a Settings page for my app. It's coming together but it doesn't show the current setting (see image).[image]

As it stands, my XML file is

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Pager Tone">

 <ListPreference
     android:entries="@array/pagerName"
     android:entryValues="@array/pagerFile"
     android:key="pagerSound"
     android:title="Select Pager Tone"
     android:defaultValue="pager"/>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/partner_message">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="partner"
        android:title="@string/send_to_partner"
        android:summary="@string/partner_summary"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:dependency="partner"
        android:defaultValue="@string/shout"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:key="partner_textmessage"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="@string/partner_textmessage" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:dependency="partner"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:key="partner_phone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="@string/partner_phone_no"
        android:summary="Starting +44"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

and the fragment java file is

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat{

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_pref, rootKey);
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that it can be done with android:summary, but I can't work out how to extract the values to put in the summaries. Nor how to make them update immediately. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well by trying numerous different search terms in Google I finally found the answer, and it was staggeringly simple. Just add app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true". So the XML becomes

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Pager Tone">

 <ListPreference
     android:entries="@array/pagerName"
     android:entryValues="@array/pagerFile"
     android:key="pagerSound"
     android:title="Select Pager Tone"
     android:defaultValue="pager"
     app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>
```